# Numeric sort of a stream that keeps alpha order when the number is the same

Tags: javascript, sorting

I tried a few of the regex sorts I found on SO, but I think they may not like the + symbol in the stream i'm needing to sort.
So I'm getting a data stream that looks like this (3 to 30 letters '+' 0 to 64000 number)

```
userString = "AAA+800|BBB+700|CCC+600|ZZZ+500|YYY+400|XXX+300|XXA+300|XXZ+300";
```

the output needs to be in the format:

```
array[0] = "XXA+300" // 300 being the lowest num and XXA being before XXX
array[...]
array[7] = "AAA+800"
```

I wish to order it from lowest num to highest num and reversed.
Here is my inefficient code. which loops 8x8 times. (my stream maybe 200 items long)

It works, but it looks messy. Can someone help me improve it so it uses less iterations?

```
var array = userString.split('|');

array.sort();

for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {         // array2 contains just the numbers
    bits = array[i].split('+');
    array2[i] = bits[1];
}

array2.sort();
if(sort_order==2)
    array2.reverse();

var c=0;
for(var a=0;a<len;a++) {            // loop for creating array3 (the output)
    for(var i=0; i<len ; i++) {     // loop thru array to find matching score   
        bits = array[i].split('+'); 
        if(bits[1] == array2[a]) {  // found matching score
            array3[c++] = bits[0]+'+'+bits[1];  // add to array3
            array[i]='z+z';     // so cant rematch array position
        }
    }
}
array = array3;
```

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please forgive the terse answer (and lack of testing), as I'm typing this on an iPhone.

```
var userArr = userString.split('|');

userArr.sort(function(a, b) {
  var aArr = a.split('+'),
      bArr = b.split('+'),
      aLetters = aArr[0],
      bLetters = bArr[0],
      aNumbers = parseInt( aArr[1] ),
      bNumbers = parseInt( bArr[1] );

  if (aNumbers == bNumbers) {
    return aLetters.localeCompare( bLetters );
  }

  return aNumbers - bNumbers;
  /*
  // Or, for reverse order:
  return -(aNumbers - bNumbers);

  // or if you prefer to expand your terms:
  return -aNumbers + bNumbers;

  */
});
```

Basically we're splitting on `|` then doing a custom sort in which we split again on `+`. We convert the numbers to integers, then if they differ (e.g. `300` and `800`) we compare them directly and return the result (because in that case the letters are moot). If they're the same, though (`300` and `300`) we compare the first parts (`XXA` and `XXX`) and return that result (assuming you want an ordinary alphabetical comparison). In this fashion the whole array is sorted.

I wasn't entirely sure what you meant by "and reversed" in your question, but hopefully this will get you started.

As you may've guessed this isn't totally optimal as we do `split` and `parseInt` on every element in every iteration, even if we already did in a previous iteration. This could be solved trivially by pre-processing the input, but with just 200 elements you probably won't see a huge performance hit.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, um reversed, as in, the numbers are reversed, but the alpha still stays in order. Actually I get this error: Object 800 has no method 'localeCompare'

Comment: What browser? The error suggests that you're calling `localeCompare` on an object that isn't a string. Debug it as you would any other error. Make sure `userArr`, `aLetters`, and `bLetters` contain what you expect them to on each iteration. If they don't, figure out why.

If you want the numbers reversed just change `return aLetters.localeCompare...` to `return -aLetters.localeCompare...`. Further reading: [(1)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) [(2)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: @Jordan, Typing a post on a phone? Either a hero or an addict :-)

Comment: See, that took minutes to figure out. I was calling `localeCompare` on `aNumbers`, which clearly will contain a number, not a string. I've fixed my answer to do the correct operation. To amend my last comment, that should be "change `return aNumbers - bNumbers;` to `return -(aNumbers - bNumbers);`". I've added a comment in the code to that effect. (@Kos Or a masochist. ;) )

Comment: @Jordan, He looks like a hero :-)